# Changing font style of rails "notices" =>

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following notice when a user logs out of my website.

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Logged out!"
end
```

Only slight little bugbear, the "Logged out!" notice is in a sans font style, rather than a font style more in keeping with my website (i.e., `font-family: sans-serif`).

How do I go about changing this...?

Perhaps:

```
def destroy
  session[:user_id] = nil
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => <div class="some_class">"Logged out!</div>
end
```

Where we can then edit the `.some_class` class within css...

Here is the application.html.crb code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome!</title>

        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    </head>

    <body>

    <!--<div id="user_nav">
            <% if current_user %>
              Logged in as <%= current_user.email %>.
              <%= link_to "Log Out", log_out_path %>
            <% else %>
              <%= link_to "Sign Up", sign_up_path %> or
              <%= link_to "Log In", log_in_path %>
            <% end %>
        </div>-->

    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
    <% end %>

    <%= yield %>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Flashes are used only for the text, if you need any styling then add that to the flash container css

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Which .css file do I need to edit? Should I edit .flash in application.css...?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It doesn't seem to be work. I have: .flash {font-family: sans-serif;} in the application css. Is this correct?

Comment: where's the view code for the flashes, did u add it in your application layout?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I'll add the code from application.html.crb into the question, tell me any omissions...

Answer (score 0):

Within application.html.crb, edit the following:

```
<div class="flash">
  <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Where there you go, you need to add the class there

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}", class: 'flash' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: then the css isn't applied, inspect your html and verify that the class and the css is sent to the browser

Comment: The above returns: SyntaxError in WelcomeController#homepage

Comment: well I tested it and the syntax is valid, if there's any problem it's on your side